# With my DLL and DLL.config in the GAC, how can I override default settings?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-4.5, gac

In our situation, we have decided to write a global assembly that can be accessed by our in-house software. This util.dll houses our connection strings and various settings in a config.dll (and seemingly within the dll itself?), and a sendmail procedure currently.

My question is why are my applications able to access the settings when I put the dll into the gac and leave out the config file? And why, when I put the config file into the folder with the dll and make a change to the config file, the applications that access the settings still pull the original setting the dll was compiled with? I've read that the dll holds default settings, and the config can be changed to override the settings, but this does not seem to be working within the gac folder.

Any insight?

Comment: A .config file is never stored in the GAC.  An application never uses a .config file that is associated with a DLL.  Only the one matching the name of the .exe is ever used.  You'll need to think this through a bit, clearly you're on the wrong path.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341368/c-net-read-the-default-value-from-config-at-runtime/28348547#28348547